# Git - Adding new feature to my project but not live yet. Need to do a quick update and push to live but without that new feature

Tags: git, github

I have a git project with two branches

1. development
2. master

I am working on a feature and pushed them to remote development branch.

Lets say I have 10 commits now in development branch and my master branch has 6 commits. The additional 4 commits in development branch has the new feature that I am working on.

Now I need to do a quick update and do the release without the new feature.

I can create a new branch[development-bk] to backup the development branch and reset the development branch to 6th commit and made a change and then merge with master.

Then checkout to development branch and merge development-bk branch and fix the conflicts.

I would like to know if there are any better options for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use git-flow workflow model, it is exactly for such feature and releases purpose.IT will save you all the manual hassle.

**Gitflow Workflow defines a strict branching model designed around the project release. This provides a robust framework for managing larger projects.**

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow.
[article by the author](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

to install in Linux

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git-flow
```